# How Do I Reference Columns In The Arrays So The Numbers Aren't Hardcoded?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am trying to make this as dynamic as possible. Is there a way to have the Arrays reference columns instead of them being hardcoded?

The code I have is below and was provided by another gracious member of the community.

```
Sub Trend()
Dim knownX, knownY, newX, TrendY
Dim i As Long


knownY = Array(0.00071, 0.00444, 0.00426, 0.00419, 0.00721, 0.00701, 0.00698, 0.01015, 0.01001, 0.00996, 0.01275, 0.01278)
knownX = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
newX = Array(13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36)
TrendY = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Trend(knownY, knownX, newX)
For i = LBound(TrendY) To UBound(TrendY)
    Debug.Print "X: " & newX(i - 1), "Y: " & TrendY(i)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you messing with Excel functions in Access?

Comment: It is the only way to use the Trend function for what I need. It works great with the hardcoded numbers, but I need it to calculate it by pulling numbers from the respective columns.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a table with your `X` and `Y` values, you can load them into a recordset and loop through the recordset to add those values to your `knownX` and `knownY` arrays.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSelect As String
Dim knownX() As Long
Dim knownY() As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim lngRows As Long

strSelect = "SELECT yt.X, yt.Y" & vbCrLf & _
    "FROM YourTable AS yt" & vbCrLf & _
    "ORDER BY yt.X;"
Debug.Print strSelect

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSelect, dbOpenSnapshot)
With rs
    If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
        .MoveLast
        lngRows = .RecordCount
        ReDim knownX(lngRows - 1)
        ReDim knownY(lngRows - 1)
        .MoveFirst
        i = 0
        Do While Not .EOF
            knownX(i) = !X
            knownY(i) = !y
            .MoveNext
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox "Oops, no data."
    End If
    .Close
End With
```

I don't know what you have in mind for the `newX` array.  But that tested code should get you part of the way towards your goal.

Comment: Hi HANS! So, should just throw that right above the code I had before in the Module? Forgive me, I am very new to this.

Comment: OK, include that code in a VBA procedure --- a `Sub` or `Function` --- similar to how you make `Sub Trend ...`.